# react native application not bundling

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run my application from `Xcode version 10.3` and `react native version 0.57.8` 
 open a terminal Running Metro Bundler on port 8081. and it's done but the simulation did not bundle project brings an older version.

I tried to delete node_modules again install and same way for pod file but it's still not working also I tried clear bundle but still not bundle my project?

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding overflow: 'hidden' as below

```
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;

<View style={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT , width: SCREEN_WIDTH ,overflow:'hidden' }}>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native' }}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
        />
</View>
```